# SSL only works without www

Tags: ssl, nginx, server, ssl-certificate

My SSL certificate works perfectly if my URL is `site.com` but not `www.site.com`. Why is this, and how can I fix it? When I configured my CSR and certificate, it said to use `mysite.com` as the domain, and not `www.mysite.com`, as it auto-configures `www`.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.key;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-$
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;



server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/mysite/public/_main;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;

    # HSTS - 6 months
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains";
    resolver 192.0.2.1;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            if ($uri !~ "^/assets/images/") {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            }
            fastcgi_index landing.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's the opposite that is true.  If you specify www.yoursite.com as the common name in your CSR, then the certificate will work with www.yoursite.com and yoursite.com.

Comment: As shown [here](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/csr) it says: "The www subdomain is added automatically by the CA, for example, example.com will secure both example.com and www.example.com"

Comment: According to the documentation that you referenced, it the CA should have added both example.com and www.example.com to the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field on the x509 certificate, when the certificate was created.  Can you open the certificate on your system, and take a look at the Subject Alternative Name field, and check if both example.com and www.example.com are included in this field?

Comment: Yep, it only says that it's for `site.com`, not `www`. How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: You might want to get a support ticket in to Gandi.  Or, if it's a Gandi free 'standard' certificate, you may want to just start over, and specify www.example.com as the common name, and it should also include example.com as well in the SAN when they issue the certificate.